# Converting from base 10 to any base between 2 and 36

Tags: c++, ascii, converters, radix

I'm writing a C++ code that converts an unsigned base 10 integer to any other base between 2 and 36. I haven't coded in a while so I'm kind of re-learning everything. My questions are: how can I keep it to just printf, without the cout at the end, and still display the ascii value. And is it possible to make it simple(basic).Sorry if I didn't format properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int InitialNum, BaseNum, Num, x;
    string FinalNum, Temp;

    printf("Enter an unsigned integer of base ten: \n");//Prompt user for     input
    scanf_s("%d", &InitialNum);
    printf("Enter the base you want to convert to (min2, max36): \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &BaseNum);            
    x = InitialNum; //save the base 10 number to display at the end


    while (InitialNum != 0) //continue dividing until original input is 0
    {              
        Num = InitialNum % BaseNum;  //save remainder to Num                         
        int ascii = 48; //declare conversion variable (from int to char)            
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)//for loop converts Num from int 0-15 to char '0'-'9', 'A'-'F'
        {
            if(Num == i)
            Temp = ascii;                 
            ascii += 1;                                 
            if (ascii == 58)//skip from 9 to A on the ascii table and continue
            ascii = 65;
        }                         
        FinalNum = Temp + FinalNum;//add to the final answer(additions to the left)                       
        InitialNum /= BaseNum; //the initial base10 number gets divided by the base and saved as the quotient              
    }        
    printf("The number %d converted to base %d is:", x, BaseNum); 
    cout<<(FinalNum);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See http://web.archive.org/web/20150204050528/http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/~slowe/cpp/itoa.html for a nice exposition of the innards of `itoa` (a non-standard common function). Oh wait, the moved version is still online, at http://www.strudel.org.uk/itoa/

Comment: Why are you using hard coded ascii values like `48` instead of putting `'0'`? You tagged this as C++ so why are you concerned about printf and scanf? Learn to use cin and cout.

Comment: our professor wants us to get familiar with printf and scanf.

Comment: i fixed the ascii issue that kfsone mentioned. I still need to fix the cout issue...

Comment: @noobisko What's the _`cout` issue_ actually? You have to replace it with `printf()`?`

Comment: yes, i want to be able to produce the ascii value(example 15=F) using the printf function.... sorry for my noobishness

Answer (score 0):

In order to output a `std::string` with `printf` you have to serve it to `printf` as a null-terminated string, the C style string. Or, well, you don't absolutely *have* to: you could print one character at a time. But it's most easy and practical to serve it as a null-terminated string.

You can do that via the `.c_str()` member function, hence:

```
printf( "%s\n", FinalString.c_str() );
```

Note that using `std::string` can be expensive at this low level of things, due to the dynamic allocation(s). E.g., (http://www.strudel.org.uk/itoa/), timing various implementations of `itoa`, found a 40x penalty.